# Azure Cloud Service Not Loading in Deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have an ASP.NET app that I am trying to deploy to Azure Cloud. It works locally but not when I deploy it. Below is my Service Definition file. The certificate "cuteanimals" is self assigned and I have already added it in Azure. 
The URL is http://cuteanimals.cloudapp.net/

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="ImageSharingWithCloudService" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2013-03.2.0">
  <WebRole name="WebRole" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="EndpointHTTPS" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="EndpointHTTPS" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="cuteanimals" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
      <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
    </Imports>
    <Certificates>
      <Certificate name="cuteanimals" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
    </Certificates>
  </WebRole>
  <WorkerRole name="ImageValidation" vmsize="Small">
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
      <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
      <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
    </Imports>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Certificates>
    </Certificates>
  </WorkerRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only opened https endpoint on your website.  I've navigated to https://cuteanimals.cloudapp.net/ and it looks OK

You will want to add another endpoint for port 80

Comment: Wow, thank you so much I didn't even realize that I had to put https, I just assumed the link on the dashboard would give me that.